YoloV5 and Raspberry Camera module (qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display :0)
I am trying to setup YoloV5 with live object detection on my Raspbery Pi 4. It has Raspberry Pi camera module connected to it. I confirmed it working with rpicam-still which does take a photo.
When I try to start detect.py I get below error. I did try to fix with ChatGPT but no luck. I did search on Google and did not come across something which helped me further, I only know that it has to do with finding my screen or see? I am a bit lost. How do I fix this?
(fiddle) a@raspberrypi:~/Projects/python/yolov5 $ python detect.py --weights yolov5s.pt --source 0
detect: weights=['yolov5s.pt'], source=0, data=data/coco128.yaml, imgsz=[640, 640], conf_thres=0.25, iou_thres=0.45, max_det=1000, device=, view_img=False, save_txt=False, save_format=0, save_csv=False, save_conf=False, save_crop=False, nosave=False, classes=None, agnostic_nms=False, augment=False, visualize=False, update=False, project=runs/detect, name=exp, exist_ok=False, line_thickness=3, hide_labels=False, hide_conf=False, half=False, dnn=False, vid_stride=1
YOLOv5 ð€ v7.0-361-gc5ffbbf1 Python-3.11.2 torch-2.3.1 CPU

Fusing layers... 
YOLOv5s summary: 213 layers, 7225885 parameters, 0 gradients, 16.4 GFLOPs
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display :0
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/home/akif/Projects/python/fiddle/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb.

Aborted

